# SQL COUNT if a specific value is found and output in the same line

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, case

I need some help with the query below. 
I have for example the following data set:

[image]

and I need to get the following output:
[image]

I tried with a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT 
    id, ValA, count(1)
FROM dual
GROUP BY id, ValA;
```

but it is not working as expected. It's basically duplicating the values in the output:
[image]

Would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count(*)` counts all rows. `count(ValA`) counts non-null values. That means `count(*) - count(ValA)` counts null's.

```
SELECT 
    id, count(*) - count(ValA), count(ValA)
FROM dual
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I've been playing around with CASE/WHEN and just can't believe it was so simple :( Thank you very much for your prompt response!!!